# How to track Google conversions with Joomla Chronoforms?

Tags: joomla, google-ads-api, chronoforms

I have multiple form pages and one thank you-page. 
I want to track if a form has successfully submitted, but I don't know how.

When a user submits a form and gets redirected to the thank you page, it'll add different parameters to the url of the thank you page. This depends on where the user came from.

E.g www.mywebsite.com/page/nameofpage?chronoform=nameofpage&event=submit

How can I track this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set this up completely outside of Chronoforms.  Within Google Analytics, go to Admin section, then Goals and set up a new website goal.  The key is to select it to be a **destination** type goal and set that to your thank you page url.  
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en
If you want to have the conversion work in Google Adwords conversions as well, you will need to add a code snippet to a custom HTML module in the debug position: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6331314

Comment: I have to correct myself: When somebody successfully submits a form, the same page gets reloaded with some parameters in the URL and a thankfulmessage is getting displayed at the bottom of the page. Just to be sure there is no misunderstanding. So I can track that with setting up destination type goals?

Comment: Yes, on the second link I put, check out "Dynamically generated or variable URLs" . You will want to include the correct parameters on the destination URL.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use two conversion trackings for the same thing because you would end up double counting your conversions.

I see that your url has an event. Instead of using destination goals in google analytics you can use events to track a goal. After you do this you will have to link google analytics with google adwords and import the goal in google adwords.

Have in mind that conversion tracking from google analytics has a big conversion lag. Having said that, the best option is to use google adwords conversion tracking but this would require to have a unique url for each thank you page.